# Quick way to insert interface methods to a class in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, interface, methods

I know that in Eclipse, if your class implements an interface or extends an abstract class, there is a quick way to add the method definitions to your class. Can this be done with VS2005? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is language specific but

For C#: Right click on the interface, navigate to Implement Inteface and choose the explicit or implict option.  The same menu is available for abstract classes (slightly different name)

There is also a smart tag that will show up on a C# interface / abstract base with the same options.  The hot key to get this to popup is "CTRL+."

For VB.Net: Simply hit Enter after the interface name and the methods will be auto-populated.

Answer (score 3):

With your insertion point in the name of the interface, hit Alt-Shift-F10, then enter.

Same thing works to automatically add using statements. (ie. Alt-Shift-F10 is the keyboard command to show that menu the little blue underline thing represents)

Edit: I think this is C#-only -- I rarely use VB.Net

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the interface name and you'll get a hover-dropdown, which will contain menu options to implicitly or explicitly implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the interface name `IInterface1`

```
public class Class1 : IInterface1
```

Select "Implement Interface" from the context menu.